# Is it a good practice to use setTimeout inside a on click handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rxjs

Is it a good practice to use setTimeout inside a on click handler in React without using clearTimeout?
In this example when user click I want to show an alert window it seems to me adding an useEffect with a clearTimout for the unmounted it is not necessary.

What do you think?

```
export const App = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.alert('hello');
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This question requests opinions. I suggest you edit it.

Comment: It's not that it is generally a good or bad practice. Either you want to use `clearTimeout` in your application, or you don't, it only depends on your requirements. This is really unanswerable since you haven't even stated the reason why you are using `setTimeout` in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue would arise where the `alert` will still happen even if the component unmounts.

To better learn how to handle events and effects in React, I recommend:

- https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects
- https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects

To fix your immediate problem, you can use keep a reference to your `timer` and call `clearTimeout` when the component unmounts.

```
import * as R from "react"

export const App = () => {

  const timer = R.useRef(null) // timer reference

  R.useEffect(() => {
    return () => { // unmount callback
      if (timer.current != null) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer.current) // clear timer
      }
    }
  }, [])

  const handleClick = () => {
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => { // new timer reference
      window.alert('hello');
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```